# How to convert an image to data in iphone

Tags: iphone

can anyone tell me how to convert an image(PNG) to data in iphone

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

here image is an UIImage object

Comment: That was surprisingly easier than I thought!

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // PNG conversion 
NSData* pictureData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image); //JPEG conversion
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to getdata from image from bundle then its similar just you specify the path for it.
Below is the code to get data from your PNG image by this way.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```